# Multi OS Windows along with ubuntu

Tags: installation, dual-boot

i have just heard about Ubuntu..I am totally new to it...But I am impressed by the os features..but I have windows 7 installed in my Toshiba laptop...I have some questions to be answer before installing Ubuntu in my laptop..

1. Can I use windows 7 along with Ubuntu?
2. Will my original windows os will be deactivated post the installation?
3. What are the benefits or better features seen in Ubuntu as compared to those in Windows

Also I have bada os(Samsung wave 3) in my phone, will I will able to install Ubuntu on it?

Answer (score 1):

Answers -

1. For Installing Ubuntu along with Windows7 as Dual Boot [Click here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)
2. Your original windows OS will be not deactivated after the installation, if you do it in a right way as explained in the link before.
3. For knowing the benefits [click here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2013431/10-reasons-to-choose-ubuntu-12-10-over-windows-8.html) and [here.](http://techluminati.com/operating-systems/linux-vs-windows/)

Hope my answer helped you.

Advice always do a google search before questioning here. Even its already being asked before many time on ask ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes You Can
2. Nope Not At All
3. the benefits are that Ubuntu is a faster And free system. its free to install and it does not have viruses. FOr More details about the features of Ubuntu: http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/features

To Dual Boot, Simply Create A Bootable On Windows Using A USB Or CD
USB Guide: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows
CD Guide: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows
Then When installing Ubuntu Click Install Alongside Windows Or Create A Different Partition.

You can try Ubuntu before Installing it by creating a bootable and then clicking Try Ubuntu.

Enjoy!